# Unknown Android devices in Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

In Google Play when I go to an app (e.g. Facebook) It says this app is compatible with all your devices (I have no Android devices currently) and shows 'No carrier GT-I9100' (Samsung Galaxy S II) and 'No carrier Samsung GT-N7000' (Samsung Galaxy Note) I have never touched one of these devices and they don't show up on my device history. How Can I remove them?

Please help!

Cheers,
Caleb

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! If you have no Android devices, I wonder a) what you're doing with Android apps and b) what makes this an Android question. IMHO it's rather something concerning the Google web site, and should rather be reported there.

Comment: There is no Google Contact form I'm aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever used an emulator or something similar?

If so, then these are those devices.

You can hide them (https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2407656), but it's very buggy

Otherwise you can log out of all devices at once by going to gmail on a computer, scrolling down and on the left side there is a link to your account activity, from that link you can log out of all devices

Make sure to change your password too, if you have no idea about these devices